# Not able to vacuum table in greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I have created a table in Greenplum and performing insert update delete operation on it. I have run vacuum command on the table, showing it ran successfully.
However when I run the command `select * from gp_toolkit.gp_bloat_diag;`. It displays same table name. 
After repeatedly running vacuum also display table name in list from command select * from gp_toolkit.gp_bloat_diag;
How should I make sure table does not have any bloat and vacuumed properly?

Answer (score 1):

For clarification:

VACUUM does remove bloat (the dead tuples in a table), and allows that space to be re-used by new tuples.

The difference between VACUUM and VACUUM FULL is that FULL re-writes the relfiles ( the table storage ) and reclaims the space for the OS.

gp_toolkit.gp_bloat_diag doesn't update in immediately, but updates shortly after an ANALYZE when the stats for the table have been updated.

I would only recommend that you run VACUUM FULL if the table is very small or if a system catalog table has grown out of proportion, where you don't have a lot of options.

VACUUM FULL is a very expensive operation. 
On a very large table can lead to unexpected run time and during this run the table will be on exclusive lock the whole time.

In general, frequent VACUUM will save your tables from growing unnecessarily large. The dead tuples will be removed and the space will be reused.

If you have a large table with significant bloat and a lot of dead space, you will likely want to reorganize -- which is a less expensive way to reclaim space.

`alter table <table_name> set with (reorganize=true) distributed (randomly -- or -- by (<column_names1>,<column_names2>....)`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this to know [Different option to remove bloat from a table](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/206578327-What-are-the-different-option-to-remove-bloat-from-a-table)

VACUUM will not remove bloat but VACUUM FULL will. Check below example

Table Creation:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testbloat;
CREATE TABLE testbloat
    (
      id       BIGSERIAL NOT NULL
    , dat_year INTEGER
    )
    WITH (OIDS = FALSE)
    DISTRIBUTED BY (id);
```

Inserting 1M records into table :

```
INSERT INTO testbloat (dat_year) VALUES(generate_series(1,1000000));
```

Checking the size of the table. Size is 43MB

```
SELECT 'After Inserting data',pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('testbloat'));
```

Updating all the records in the table

```
UPDATE testbloat
SET dat_year = dat_year+1;
```

Checking the size of the table after updating. Size is 85MB. It is increased because of bloat which was caused because of update operation

```
SELECT 'After updating data',pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('testbloat'));
```

Applying VACUUM on the table

```
Vacuum testbloat;
```

Checking the size of the table after VACUUM. Size is still 85MB.

```
SELECT 'After Vacuum', pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('testbloat'));
```

Applying VACUUM FULL on the table

```
Vacuum FULL testbloat;
```

Checking the size of the table after VACUUM FULL. Size is still 43MB. It got reduced as the table bloat was not there

```
SELECT 'After Vacuum FULL ', pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('testbloat'));
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, regarding the statement Vacuum FULL avee_dev.year1; what is avee_dev.year1 ?

Comment: Sorry abot that. I changed it

Comment: ok great. I am using talend job and every hour updating and inserting and deleting records into 20 tables. What should be the frequency by which I should vacuum the table? should I vacuum just after insert, update and delete or once in a day?

Comment: Once a day is better

Answer (score 0):

Vacuum never releases the space occupied by expired rows rather it mark those space to be reused for later insert of new rows to the same table itself. Hence, even after you run vaccum, the size of the table won't come down.

Instead of using vaccum full , use CTAS , it is faster than vaccum full and unlike vaccum full it does not hold locks on pg_class table.

And after CTAS operations, rename the table to the old table name.